# ZF2 model query with BINARY

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

Hi i need a login with a case sensitive username..

I tried to use the generated query from my zf2 model using mysql in terminal and in works fine, but it my zf2 it does not work well.

my mysql code:

```
SELECT *
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN role AS role 
    ON role.id = user.role 
LEFT JOIN info AS i 
    ON i.userId = user.id 
WHERE BINARY user.username = 'username' 
   AND user.password = 'password';
```

my zf2 code:

```
$select = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
$select->from('user')
->columns(array('primary'=>'id','username','password','salt','role','acti
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fixed this by changing the column of my table into a case sensitive( ..._cs ) Collation